# Realtime multiplayer game along side REST api

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm a Rails developer who has just migrated to Node and I've decided to write an angular application backed by an postgres/express.js REST api. I use the api primarily for CRUD operations thus far, but I want to start a realtime game instance when two players visit a certain page(challenge each other). I'm thinking of using socket.io to accomplish the realtime functionality.

The game is similar to that of pokemon on gameboy, in which to players take turn performing certain actions until one of them wins.

I have the following questions:

1. Should I have a separate server to handle the game using socket.io, or can i use the same as the one my API operates on?
2. Should I use a service like Pusher or can I create the architecture myself?
3. How would I go about making sure no data is lost, if say, a player disconnects during a game?
4. At which point (number of concurrent connections/request per second) would I run into performance issues? 100, 1000, 10000?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. If the realtime logic is closely related to the CRUD stuff (i.e. realtime events are a direct result of writes to the API), and you expect somewhat equal usage of both aspects of the system, then I'd put both on the same server.
2. I highly recommend using a realtime push service if possible (disclaimer: I work for Fanout.io). It'll be simpler and probably less expensive too.
3. The key to making sure data is not lost is to persist it on the server before sending. Don't depend on the realtime layer for persistence (biggest mistake you can make). When the client reconnects, it can request data it may have missed via the normal API. So, just get your CRUD stuff correct and then layer realtime eventing on top. You can create a very network resilient service this way.
4. You should be able to get to a few hundred concurrent connections without much thought. Going beyond will take architecture planning. Of course, if you delegate to a push service then you don't have to worry about this, at least for the realtime part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what exactly does architecture planning encompass?

Comment: I just mean that you may need to buy larger servers, take advantage of many cores per server (run multiple node instances?), load balance among many servers, optimize your network interactions to achieve more throughput per server, etc.